# Remove the period at the end of the subcaption using \subbottom with memoir

Tags: captions, memoir, subfloats, subcaption

I am using the `memoir` package (with `hyperref` package in case that makes a difference) and I am using `\subbottom` to place subfigures within a figure environment. I simply want the subcaptions to read (a) and (b), which is automatically handled, so I have left the caption empty (as shown below). However, the final output when I compile my code has a period after the (a) such that my figures are labelled (a). and (b). Any ideas on how to remove the period?

```
\begin{figure}[bt]
 \centering
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{imagea}\label{fig:imagea}}
    \hfill
    \subbottom[]{\includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{imageb}\label{fig:imageb}}\\
    \caption{Images}
    \label{fig:images}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi and [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: why not using th `subcaption` package?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found my problem while trying to produce a minimum working example. The .sty file I am using had modified the default subcaption to `\@makesubfloatcaption{\@nameuse{@the#1}}{#3.}}'. Removing the full stop produced the desired effect.